# Golang: How to implement the transfer method/function

Tags: go

I've the following domain. How do we implement the `Transfer` functionality that can transfer an `amount` from one account to another account. I should be able be transfer from a savings to checking and vice versa. I OOP world, a super type makes it easier. I am wondering how we accomplish this in Go.

```
type AccountData struct {
    Num      string
    Name     string
    OpenDate time.Time
    Balance  float64
}

type SavingsAccount struct {
    InterestRate float32
    AccountData
}

type CheckingAccount struct {
    TransactionFee float32
    AccountData
}

type Account interface {
    Deposit(amount float64) error
    Withdraw(amount float64) error
}

//constructor functions
func OpenSavingsAccount(no string, name string, openingDate time.Time) SavingsAccount {
    return SavingsAccount{
        AccountData: AccountData{Num: no,
            Name:     name,
            OpenDate: openingDate,
        },
        InterestRate: 0.9,
    }
}

func OpenCheckingAccount(no string, name string, openingDate time.Time) CheckingAccount {
    return CheckingAccount{
        AccountData: AccountData{Num: no,
            Name:     name,
            OpenDate: openingDate,
        },
        TransactionFee: 0.15,
    }
}

//Account methods
func (acct *SavingsAccount) Withdraw(amount float64) error {
    if acct.Balance < amount {
        return errors.New("Not enough money to withdraw")
    }
    acct.Balance = acct.Balance - amount
    return nil
}


func (acct *SavingsAccount) Deposit(amount float64) error {
    fmt.Printf("Depositing %f \n", amount)
    acct.Balance = acct.Balance + amount
    return nil
}
func (acct *CheckingAccount) Deposit(amount float64) error {
    fmt.Printf("Depositing %f \n", amount)
    acct.Balance = acct.Balance + amount
    return nil
}
func (acct *CheckingAccount) Withdraw(amount float64) error {
    if acct.Balance < amount {
        return errors.New("Not enough money to withdraw")
    }
    acct.Balance = acct.Balance - amount
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func Transfer(to, from Account, amount float64) error {
    if err := from.Withdraw(amount); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := to.Deposit(amount); err != nil {
        if err := from.Deposit(amount); err != nil {
            // `from` should be alerted that their money
            // just vanished into thin air
        }
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

As an exercise, it might be worthwhile to design an interface in which transactions are [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)).

Comment: so it should be a function. I was trying to implement it as a method i.e. Transfer is part of Account interface type.

Comment: @AravindR.Yarram: Pass pointers to your structs: https://play.golang.org/p/dvBRS7xzQN

Comment: Thanks. Why does pointer work while regular reference isn't? I am unable to understand the reasoning.

Comment: @AravindR.Yarram: Because the `Transfer` interface methods are defined on pointers of both `SavingsAccount` (`(acct *SavingsAccount)`) and `CheckingAccount` (`(acct *CheckingAccount)`), and not values of them (`(acct SavingsAccount)`, `(acct CheckingAccount)`).